Replacing a method call via reflection in C# does not work in a Unity environment
In Unity6 (6000.0.7f1), I've tried to redirect a method call to my own method using the MethodRedirect extension method from this GitHub repo.
From the Scenario1 example code in the GitHub repo, I produced the following code to test it:
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;

namespace MethodRedirect
{
    class Scenario1
    {
        [MenuItem("RedirectTo/Scenario1")]
        static void Test()
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Redirect : MethodRedirect.Scenario1.InternalInstanceMethod()");
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("To       : MethodRedirect.Scenario1.PrivateInstanceMethod()");

            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Scenario1));
            Type Scenario_Type = assembly.GetType("MethodRedirect.Scenario1");

            MethodInfo Scenario_InternalInstanceMethod = Scenario_Type.GetMethod("InternalInstanceMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            MethodInfo Scenario_PrivateInstanceMethod = Scenario_Type.GetMethod("PrivateInstanceMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            var token = Scenario_InternalInstanceMethod.RedirectTo(Scenario_PrivateInstanceMethod, true);

            // Using "dynamic" type to resolve the following issue in x64 and Release (with code optimizations) builds.
            //
            // Symptom: the second call to method InternalInstanceMethod() does not return the expected string value
            //
            // Cause: the result from the first call to method InternalInstanceMethod() is cached and so the second
            // call gets the cached value instead of making the call again.
            //
            // Remark: for some reason, without "dynamic" type, only the "Debug x86" build configuration would reevaluate 
            // the second call to InternalInstanceMethod() without using the cached string value.
            //
            // Also, using the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)] attribute on the method did not work.
            dynamic scenario = (Scenario1)Activator.CreateInstance(Scenario_Type);

            string methodName = scenario.InternalInstanceMethod();

            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Call MethodRedirect.Scenario1.InternalInstanceMethod => "+ methodName);

            UnityEngine.Debug.Assert(methodName == "MethodRedirect.Scenario1.PrivateInstanceMethod");

            if (methodName == "MethodRedirect.Scenario1.PrivateInstanceMethod")
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("\nRestore...");
                
                token.Restore();

                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(token);

                methodName = scenario.InternalInstanceMethod();

                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Call MethodRedirect.Scenario1.InternalInstanceMethod => "+ methodName.ToString());

                UnityEngine.Debug.Assert(methodName == "MethodRedirect.Scenario1.InternalInstanceMethod");

                if (methodName == "MethodRedirect.Scenario1.InternalInstanceMethod")
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("\nSUCCESS!");
                }
                else
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("\nRestore FAILED");                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("\nRedirection FAILED");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        
        internal string InternalInstanceMethod()
        {
            return "MethodRedirect.Scenario1.InternalInstanceMethod";
        }
        
        private string PrivateInstanceMethod()
        {
            return "MethodRedirect.Scenario1.PrivateInstanceMethod";
        }

        public string PublicInstanceMethod()
        {
            return "MethodRedirect.Scenario1.PublicInstanceMethod";
        }

        public static string PublicStaticMethod()
        {
            return "MethodRedirect.Scenario1.PublicStaticMethod";
        }
    }
}

Now when choosing the RedirectTo->Scenario1 Menu, the console shows the following:

Any ideas about what could cause this failure and how to get this running?
